# Bootstrap Datetimepicker Remaing Number of Seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I am creating task again service and each service has number of hours
so when i log manually log time i want datetimepicker to only log reaming number of seconds
EX:
Step 1. service contain 2hr
Step 2. I logged 1hr
Step 3. Now I want to add validation that user should only add reaming time in datetimepicer(1hr)

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timezone_offset_minutes = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
    $('#timezone').val(timezone_offset_minutes);
    $('#startTime, #endTime').timepicker({
        minuteStep: 1,
        showSeconds: true,
        secondStep: true,
    }).on('hide.timepicker', function (e) {
        calculateTime();
    });

    jQuery('#start_date, #end_date').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
    }).on('hide', function (e) {
        calculateTime();
    });
    calculateTime();
    function calculateTime() {
        var startDate = $('#start_date').val();
        var endDate = $('#end_date').val();
        var startTime = $("#startTime").val();
        var endTime = $("#endTime").val();

        var timeStart = new Date(startDate + " " + startTime);
        var timeEnd = new Date(endDate + " " + endTime);

        var diff = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 60000; //dividing by seconds and milliseconds

        var minutes = diff % 60;
        var hours = (diff - minutes) / 60;
        var seconds = Math.floor(minutes * (60));
        var calSeconds =  seconds % 60; 

        if (hours < 0 || minutes < 0) {
            var numberOfDaysToAdd = 1;
            timeEnd.setDate(timeEnd.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
            var dd = timeEnd.getDate();

            if (dd < 10) {
                dd = "0" + dd;
            }

            var mm = timeEnd.getMonth() + 1;

            if (mm < 10) {
                mm = "0" + mm;
            }

            var y = timeEnd.getFullYear();

            $('#end_date').val(mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y);
            calculateTime();
        }
        else {
            $('#total_time').html(hours + " Hours " + Math.floor(minutes) + " Minutes " + calSeconds + " Seconds ");
        }

    }
</script>
```

and here is remaing number of seconds i am getting from controller
{{$subsSeconds}} //9 seconds

Comment: Could you please explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve and what your question is?

Comment: I am creating web application based on Task Management System
each task is in relationship with service and each service has number of hours
i log time with automated timer and its working fine its only log 2hr(Number of hours on service)
but i want to do same on manually log time option
when i am getting input time from user
i want to enter limited number of seconds(remaining time of service)

Comment: @Tim 
User should not be able to enter end time more than remaining number of seconds

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't validate these things in javascript, since this is executed on the user's computer, but in PHP on your server.

Since you're using PHP, you could use the PHP date() functions, or use an external library to calculate if the given date is past a certain point.

If you really want to do date calculations in javascript, Moment.js (https://momentjs.com/) is a pretty good javascript library for dealing with dates. Since plain old javascript isn't very good for dealing with dates (in my opinion).

Comment: I dont want to use monent in this project for some reasons and also i am using post back method so page is reloading so i have to use JavaScript validation

Comment: I do recommend using some kind if js library since plain Javascript isn't that good at calculating dates. I had some trouble with moment.js at first to, but if you take an hour (or probably less) to learn it, it can be really useful. I use it in all kinds of applications nowadays.

Comment: Yes but i want to do it with datetimepicker right now

Comment: Next i will consider your recommendation @tim